# RxCocoa error while starting the app on device

Tags: ios, xcode, rx-swift

Currently I'm having a problem with starting the app on device. After installing rxcocoa and rxswift through cocoapods - on emulator everything is good but not on device. The error says that rxcocoa cannot be found

Here is the error log:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa  Referenced
>   from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/rx_goodslist
>   Reason: no suitable image found. Did find: 
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa:
>   stat() failed with errno=25 
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa:
>   stat() failed with errno=1 
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/542D3903-715B-4FB9-9418-D25860F6F5AA/rx_goodslist.app/Frameworks/RxCocoa.framework/RxCocoa:
>   stat() failed with errno=1 (lldb)

UPDATE: SOLVED
I just commented “use_fraemworks” in pod file and everything worked well

Comment: Hope you have tried all the basic remedies, like cleaning project/derived data. etc. Try removing the framework and adding again. Make sure the framework is in embedded binaries..

Comment: Thank you. Solved

Comment: In that case, you should probably answer your own question and accept the answer, it will be easier for people seeing this question to check the answer as well.